# CompleteName_Last MediaInfo what is that mean and how to set it via FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-capture, mediainfo

I have a question relative to Complete_NameLast MediaInfo field

> CompleteName_Last         : Complete name (Folder+Name+Extension) of
>   the last file (in the case of a sequence of files)

[image]

Does any one knows how and when this field adding to file ? 
How to set it via FFMPEG ?
I was assuming that this field added with squence of video files for example we have one big source file, streaming it and than capturing via FFMPEG but at that case some files have it and some files don't.

In picture that you were seen above we have it (current file index4.ts) but with other file that was captured from the same soruce we don't have it (for example index 40.ts)

**The main questions are
 1. Where I can find additional information about ffmpeg file squence capturing 
 2. Where I can find find more information relative to this
    MediaInfo property**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a property of the file. When Mediainfo detects a sequence of media files in a folder which are consecutively named, it displays that field with the name of the last file in the sequence.